# How to re-render the react-table when selectedRowIds is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I would want to change the select by clicking the button.

At this moment the table cannt rereder when the selectedRowIds is changed.

In the react-table behaviors ,it seems that the table is rerender when data is changed

How should i do?

I have create a sample

https://codesandbox.io/s/tannerlinsley-react-table-row-selection-controlled-forked-0oq29?file=/src/App.js

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eh1mfn?file=demo.js is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @SaeedShamloo Thanks. That is what i want. May i ask is useRef() a good method to handle this situation?